# Tor Browser Installation: How to Make the Application Icon Persist?

Tags: icons, browser, tar, tor

I installed the Tor browser by first downloading the tar.xz file and extracting it using the command 'tar -xf your_file.tar.xz'. Then, to run the application, I used the command './start-tor-browser.desktop'. This process works for running the Tor browser, but when I close it, the application icon disappears, and I have to use the command './start-tor-browser.desktop' again to use it. How can I install it in a way that the icon appears, similar to installing a regular application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start-tor-browser.desktop` actually contains some instructions about how the launcher works. That also indicates how to add the launcher to your desktop menu:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

The launcher will then appear in the menu, and can be pinned to the dock.